# How do you drop the WordPress database user?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've created a LAMP server and installed WordPress 5.5 on it.  The MySQL database username for my WordPress database is called 'wp_user'.  I've granted my own administrative user account all privileges on all databases.  I'm now experimenting with various settings and would like to manually drop the WordPress user temporarily and then recreate it but I get an error when I try:

```
mysql> DROP USER wp_user;

ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'wp_user'@'%'
```

Why can't I drop this user?  Are there some processes I have to kill first?

Comment: Are you trying to remove with the root user?

Comment: I'm new to MySQL and WP.  If you mean the mysql 'root' user (there seem be three of them created by default), then no.  I'm trying to delete the MySQL database user name that's created for the WP database as is defined in the wp-config.php file.

Comment: Access via terminal: `mysql -u root -p` and then `DROP USER 'your_user'@'%';` `

Comment: @mtinsley ???  I'm not referring to a table.  I'm referring to a MySQL user account.

Comment: @Valdeir I get the same error when I do it as the root user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the user actually exists: `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user where user = 'YOUR_USER';`.

If it really exists: `flush privileges;` and then `DROP USER 'YOUR_USER'@'localhost';`

Still did not work?

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='YOUR_USER' AND host = 'localhost';

flush privileges;
```

Answer (score 0):

`flush privileges;` To tell the server to reload the grant tables.

```
DROP USER 'wp_user'@'localhost';
```

Again `flush privileges;`

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user where user = 'wp_user';
```

The query will return empty set.